Deadlocks on insert in EF Core
I have a service, where there are a lot of inserts in a certain table in a SQL Server database. Method below is triggered from a lot of places and multiple threads:
    public async Task InsertLogApi(LogApi logApi)
    {
        _context.Add(logApi);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

This method throws

SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 61) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

quite a lot.
Primary key is an int type, and it's auto incremented by database. So on SaveChanges EF Core does two requests:
INSERT INTO [...]
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15);
SELECT [Id]
FROM [...]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();"

I assume that deadlock happens when one thread is on SELECT and other on INSERT (based on this question). I added a transaction, and method now looks like this
public async Task InsertLogApi(LogApi logApi)
{
    var s = _context.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();

    await s.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
            {
                using (var t = _context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _context.Add(logApi);
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                        await t.CommitAsync();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        await t.RollbackAsync();
                    }
                }
            });
}

(we have a retry policy, so I had to use new strategy).
This solution kind of helped, we do not have deadlocks, but performance dropped a lot (like 5 times or so). I tried ReadUncommitted, it didn't help. As far as I understand I can use client-generated PK (uuid), but that is not an option right now. May be I should do something with database?
Is there a better workaround, am I missing something?

Inspect the execution plan to determine why it's slow and work out how to improve performance

Are you using snapshot isolation? Also, are there any relations (FKs) in this Log entry to other tables? Ideally something like logging that is touched everywhere by everything should have as few relations as absolutely possible. (Ideally none)

To diagnose a deadlock, we need at a minimum: the raw SQL statements that are deadlocking (all of them, and if in a transaction then all statements in the transaction), the query plans for those (please share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and the tables and index definitions involved. Without this it's impossible to properly diagnose.

Why even access the original table after the insert? Can you not transform SELECT [Id] FROM [...] WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity(); into merely SELECT scope_identity() AS [Id] WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1;?

@AlwaysLearning no, I can't transform that, that's what EF Core is doing on SaveChanges()

@AlwaysLearning It's because the table has a trigger (or EF Core thinks it does) so it wants the newest data for the row. In EF7 it's optimized to an OUTPUT, and there's proposals to opt-out of the check completely https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19056

@Charlieface why do triggers matter here - scope_identity() is not @@identity.

@AlwaysLearning Nothing to do with that. Because if a trigger actually changes the inserted/modified row, EF Core wants the new row values. Yes, without such a trigger you can just use a straight OUTPUT or SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(). Either way this question is not answerable without the info I've asked, and should be closed.
